# Please justify the use of "would" here

Tags: modal-verbs

I've been told that we can't use would for future events(expect in conditional sentences). But I have encountered many situations where native speakers use would to express future possibilities. Like in this song (Like I would)

> He won't touch you like I do
>
> He won't love you like I would
>
> He don't know your body
>
> He don't do you right
>
> He won't love you like I would
>
> Love you like I would

Comment: Please do not expect song lyrics in English to exemplify the grammar you are taught in the classroom. I'm sure there is popular music in your first language, and that the lyrical content of those songs does not reflect the highest expression of grammatical purity! In any case, all of these uses of _would_ are indeed conditional constructions.

Comment: You are right in that sense but I have come across many such sentences where speakers use would(without condition) to express future possibility.

Comment: Mary: The guy on the phone had French accent.
Peter: It would be Nathan.

Comment: I think the conditional in the song is implied: he won't love you like I would (*if I were your boyfriend*)

Comment: Ref. Nathan, that's the modal _would_ to express expectation. See KinzieB's answer [**here.**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/27492/37009)

Comment: I asked this kind of question few days ago.(http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/106683/can-we-use-some-modals-interchangeably) and someone told me that saying "I would rain tomorrow" is useless

Comment: You raise a good and very tricky issue here - saying "That would be Nathan" isn't quite the same as "it would rain tomorrow" because it's not literally a prediction about the future.  Again, I think this usage of *would* includes a kind of implied conditional: *if there were a man with a French accent calling us on the phone*, that would be Nathan.

Comment: "It would rain tomorrow" can be taken in sense of "expectation". Like we say It would be Mr.X at door then why saying "It would rain tomorrow(expectedly)" is considered incorrect?

Comment: But if you say "it would rain tomorrow", where's the implied "if"?  "It ____ rain tomorrow" is definitely a statement about the future.  "It would be Mr. X at the door" isn't exactly a statement about the future, it's a hypothetical.

Comment: @Khan Ref. both _"It would rain tomorrow"_ and  _"Peter: It would be Nathan,"_ these are examples of _would_ used to express presumption or expectation. See definition 6 at the [**American Heritage Dictionary.**](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=W5244000)

Comment: @stangdon In "It _would_ rain tomorrow" or "He _would_ say something like that", the modal expresses resigned acceptance, but I can't find (yet) a dictionary that discusses this meaning. Interesting in that it is so dependent upon context as to be nearly deictic in this usage.

Comment: The examples with "Like" are comparative constructions, not conditionals. Take the first example: "I do" is a comparative clause functioning as a manner adjunct.  The meaning is roughly "I touch you in manner x ; he will touch you in manner y way; x does not equal y" where the implication is that manner x is somehow more desirable than manner y.